# Json object to array

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js

I have an json array like this:

```
{"orders" : [ null, {
    "date" : "2012-03-19T07:22Z",
    "item" :
      {"name":"pizza", "quantity":"2", "size":"25"}, {"name":"suppe", "quantity":"2", "size":"1" }
  },{
    "date" : "2018-03-19T07:22Z",
    "item" : {"name":"brot", "quantity":"1", "size":"-"}, {"name":"hawaii", "quantity":"5", "size":"45" }
  } ]
}
```

And I would like render a nested list with  vue but I don't understand why I can't. I already passed the data, first level data can render, but secont level can not.:

```
<ul v-for="order in orders">
       <li>{{order.date}}</li>
           <li>{{order.item}}</li>
              <ul v-for="i in orders.item">
                 <li>{{i.name}}</li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Your second version isn't an array. Do you mean, just remove the null entry? `array = array.filter(x => x)`

Comment: sorry, I fixed the question.

Comment: Now your second version is invalid JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I rather wrote the whole problem, because I am newbie

Comment: You have a typo `i in orders.item` should be `i in order.item`.

Comment: I fixed the typo, but nothing better.

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid. You have one closing `li` too many.

Comment: I fixed it thank you. But didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON `item` should be an array, not an object. Also, close your `li` tag:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    orders: [
      null,
      {
        "date": "2012-03-19T07:22Z",
        "item": [{
            "name": "pizza",
            "quantity": "2",
            "size": "25"
          },
          {
            "name": "suppe",
            "quantity": "2",
            "size": "1"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "date": "2018-03-19T07:22Z",
        "item": [{
            "name": "brot",
            "quantity": "1",
            "size": "-"
          },
          {
            "name": "hawaii",
            "quantity": "5",
            "size": "45"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="order in orders" v-if="order != null">
    <li>{{order.date}}</li>
    <li>
      <ul v-for="i in order.item">
        <li>{{i.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I must be much carefullier with the brackets!